# LINQ: get access to child lists during runtime

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

i make a group by and get child lists...
during query i create a new obj with

```
var result3 = from tick in listTicks
              group tick by bla bla into g
              select new 
              { 
                  Count = g.Count(), 
                  Key = g.Key, 
                  Items = g,
                  Timestamp = g.First().timestamp,
                  LastTimestamp = g[-1].First().timestamp result3 isn't still declared???
              };
```

i want have access during runtime in the select new on values of the last created obj
maybe check if the last first.Timestamp has a specific value

is it possible to have access to the last g during creating the select new { }
i want to check an actual value withe one from the last g

i thought something like result3[result.count - 1].timestamp??? in the select new part...

Answer (score 1):

Not should I understand correctly, but is this what you want ?

```
result3.Last().Timestamp;
```

---

After comment : I think I understand now.
You need to create a temporary variable to store the timestamp of the last group and set its value in a more complex delegate :

```
int lastTimestamp = 0; // Put the correct type and default value

var result3 = (from tick in listTicks
              group tick by bla bla into g
              select g)
              .Select
              (g => 
              {
                  // Create your object with the last timestamp
                  var result = new
                  { 
                      Count = g.Count(), 
                      Key = g.Key, 
                      Items = g,
                      Timestamp = g.First().timestamp,
                      LastTimestamp = lastTimestamp
                  };
                  // Set last timestamp for next iteration
                  lastTimestamp = result.Timestamp;
                  // Return your object
                  return result;
              });
```

Don't know the exact context, but you might want to add "ToList()" to override lazy fetching.

Comment: this doesn't work... the code looks good... but in debug... the result3 does'nt have the new variable from temp result Counte, Key .... etc...